# Low Resolution on Boot, not Login

Tags: nvidia, resolution, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, xrandr

Ok, here goes:

When I was installing Nvidia drivers and Bumblebee for my 780m Optimus laptop, the Intel driver somehow made my display undetectable, making X output in the lowest resolution it could (the failsafe resolution). To counter that, I found a guide for making xrandr force my 1080p resolution. That ended up with a script that I configured to start on login:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120-hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode eDP1 "1920x1080_60.00" && xrandr --output eDP1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
```

That works great, but with one hitch: the login screen still has that horrible, low resolution, which of course goes up after logging in. But my question is: How do I run the above script so that the login screen also has a decent resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a low res boot screen. Try this:

Run in Terminal

1.sudo apt-get install v86d

2.gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

3.Replace Line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

New Line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"

5.Replace Line:#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

New Line:#GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
6.Save & Close

7.gksu gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

8.Add Line: uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
Save & Close

9.sudo update-grub2

10.sudo update-initramfs -u

Comment: What exactly are you doing? I have a GT215 that also has low-res plymouth but works fine once you log in. I want to find out if this is safe to try for me to, or if I need to change anything. Thanks!